# JavaScript Resizing not initializing on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my JavaScript cod and I am having an issue that I hope someone can help me with. The function columnConform does not fire and resize the divs until I resize the actual browser window. So the function is working but just doesn't happen until I trigger the window resize event handler. What can I do to make the function fire when all the page content and the DOM is loaded? Thanks in advance!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(function(){
    jumboSlide();
    columnConform();
});

function jumboSlide() {
    $('#jumboSlide').carousel()
}

function resetHeight() {
    $('.row-equal > div').css("min-height", 0);
}

var currentTallest = 0,
    currentRowStart = 0,
    rowDivs = new Array();

function setConformingHeight(element, newHeight) {
    element.css("min-height", newHeight);
}

function getOriginalHeight(element) {
    return (element.data("originalHeight") == undefined) ? (element.outerHeight()) : (element.data("originalHeight"));
}

function columnConform() {
    $('.row-equal > div').each(function() {
        var $element = $(this);
        var topPosition = $element.position().top;
        if (currentRowStart != topPosition) {
            for(currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) setConformingHeight(rowDivs[currentDiv], currentTallest);
            rowDivs.length = 0;
            currentRowStart = topPosition;
            currentTallest = getOriginalHeight($element);
            rowDivs.push($element);
        } else {
            rowDivs.push($element);
            currentTallest = (currentTallest < getOriginalHeight($element)) ? (getOriginalHeight($element)) : (currentTallest);
        }
        for (currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) setConformingHeight(rowDivs[currentDiv], currentTallest);
        });
}

$(window).resize(function(){
    resetHeight();
    columnConform();
});

});
```

Comment: Why don't you just call the function within the "document ready"-function?
´$(document).ready(function(){ ... columnConform(); });´

Comment: One of several approaches to this would be using `$(window).resize();` somewhere within document ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `columnConform();` at the end of you ready function.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply trigger it like so:

```
$(window).trigger('resize');
```